# SAS - Do Loops Iterations

Tags: sas

Can someone explain this code to me in depth??  I have a list of comments in the code where I am confused.  Is there anyway I can attach a csv of the data?  Thanks in advance.

```
data have;
infile "&sasforum.\datasets\Returns.csv" firstobs=2 dsd truncover;
input DATE :mmddyy10. A B B_changed;
format date yymmdd10.;
run;

data spread;
do nb = 1 by 1 until(not missing(B));
    set have;
    end;
br = B;
do i = 1 to nb;
    set have; *** I don't get how you can do i = 1 to nb with set have.  There is not variable nb on set have.  The variable nb is readinto the dataset spread;
    if nb > 1 then B_spread = (1+br)**(1/nb) - 1;
    else B_spread = B;
    output;
    end;
drop nb i br;
run;
```

***** If i comment out "drop nb i br" i get to see that nb takes a value of 2 for the null values of B.. I don't get how this is done or possible.  Because if I run the code right after the line "br = B", and put an output statement in the first do loop, I am clearly seeing that nb takes a valueof one for B null values.Honestly, It is like the first do loop is reads in future observations for B as BR. Can you please explain this to me. The second dataset "bunch" seems to follow the same type of principles as the first... So i imagine if I get a grasp on the first on how the datasetspread is created, then I will understand how bunch is created.;

Comment: You can’t attach a csv. But you can post 5-10 records of data from Returns.csv into your question. That would help. Or better yet, paste a code steps that creates work.have, with a cards statement or whatever.

Comment: Here's some instructions for creating sample data in a data step that others can just run. https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/How-to-create-a-data-step-version-of-your-data-AKA-generate/ta-p/258712

Comment: Hey guys thank for all the help, I will keep this in mind if I post another questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an advanced DATA step programming technique, commonly referred to as a DoW loop.  If you search lexjansen.com for DoW, you will find helpful papers like http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings09/038-2009.pdf.  The DoW loop codes and explicit loop around a SET statement.  This is actually a "Double-DoW loop", because you have two explicit loops.

I made some sample data, and added some PUT statements to your code:

```
data have ;
  input B ;
  cards ;
.
.
1
2
.
.
.
3
;

data spread;
  do nb = 1 by 1 until(not missing(B));
    set have;

    put _n_= "top do-loop " (nb B)(=) ;
  end;
  br = B;
  do i = 1 to nb;
    set have;
    if nb > 1 then B_spread = (1+br)**(1/nb) - 1;
    else B_spread = B;
    output;
    put _n_= "bottom do-loop " (nb B br B_spread)(=) ;
  end;
  drop nb i br;
run;
```

With that sample data, on the first iteration of the DATA step (*N*=1), the top do loop will iterate three times, reading the first three records of HAVE.  At that point, (not missing(B)) will be true, and the loop will not iterate again.  The variable NB will have a value of 3. The bottom loop will then iterate 3 times, because NB has a value of 3.  It will also read the first three records have HAVE. It will compute B_Spread, and output each record.

On the second iteration of the DATA step, the top DO loop will iterate only once.  It will read the 4th record, with B=2.  The bottom loop will iterate once, reading the 4th record, computing B_spread, and output.

On the third iteration of the DATA step, the top DO loop will iterate four times, reading the 5th through 8th records.  The bottom loop will also iterate four times, reading the 5th through 8th records, computing B_spread, and output.

On the fourth iteration of the DATA step, the step to complete, because the SET statement in the top loop will read the End Of File mark.

The core concept of a Double-DoW loop is that typically you are reading the data in groups.  Often groups are identified by an ID.  Here they are defined by sequential records read until not missing(B).  The top DO-loop reads the first group of records, and computes some value (in this case, it computes NB, the number of records in the group).  Then the bottom DO-loop reads the first group of records, and computes some new value, using the value computed in top DO-loop.  In this case, the bottom DO-loop computes B_spread, using NB.

Comment: If I could add one follow up question.. When I run the code you provided and check the log I get this:  
_N_=1 top do-loop nb=1 B=.
_N_=1 top do-loop nb=2 B=.
_N_=1 top do-loop nb=3 B=1
_N_=1 bottom do-loop nb=3 B=. br=1 B_spread=0.2599210499
_N_=1 bottom do-loop nb=3 B=. br=1 B_spread=0.2599210499            

My only question is, why when the bottom loop iterates, does nb always equal 3? 

Thanks,

Comment: On the first iteration of the data step, _n_=1, the top loop iterates three times, so at the end of that nb=3.  When the bottom loop iterates, there are no statements that change the value of nb. So nb will still have the value of 3.